# Proof $\sim (\exists x) A(x) \iff (\forall x) \sim A(x)$

Tags: logic

how can I prove that, if $A(x)$ is an open sentence with variable x, then:

$\sim (\exists x) A(x) \iff (\forall x) \sim A(x)$

By using this result:

$(\exists !x)A(x) \iff [(\forall y)(\forall z) A(y) \land A(z) \implies y=z]$

Comment: Don't use that result.  That isn't true. This is:$$(\exists ! x)~A(x)~\iff~(\exists y)(\forall z)~\big(A(y)\land (A(z)\to y=z)\big)$$"There is something that satisfies $A$, and anything that satisfies $A$ will be that something."

Comment: Actually, I am uncertain as to why you think uniqueness would be of any help at all.

Comment: There is no universal way to prove primitive concepts.  It depends on the logic you are using.